# How to get local notification on reach of particular coordinate(Lat-Long) objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am developing application which have functionality as per below.

There are many restaurants registered in application. If user reached near to any favourite restaurant then application will show Local notification for that restaurant.

I am looking for working **Objective C** code to integrate it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Create geofences for all favourite restaurants.

you can refer this guide

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/16/geofencing-ios-objectivec/

Answer (score 0):

### For iOS 10 and later

If you want to send Local Notification with `UNNotificationRequest`, you can perform this as following:

1. Ask for `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist` file. Also add Background modes to Location.

   ```
   var locationManager:CLLocationManager
   ```

   inside `viewWillAppear` wirte this to ask for AlwaysAuthorization permission

   ```
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   ```
2. Then, use either `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` or `startUpdatingLocation`, to monitor location changes.
3. Implement CLLocationManagerDelegate `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and show local notification when enters into specific location.

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){
       //Show local notification when entered a desired location
       showLocalNotification("Entered \(region.identifier)")
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion){
       //Show local notification when exit from a desired location
        showLocalNotification("Exited \(region.identifier)")
   }
   ```

### For earlier versions

If you want to use `UILocalNotification`, you can add `CLRegion` in UILocalNotification object. iOS will automatically show a local notification when user enter/exits geographical area CLRegion.

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertTitle = "Hi there"
localNotification.alertBody = "you are here"

let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 4.254, longitude: 88.25), radius: CLLocationDistance(100), identifier: "")
region.notifyOnEntry = true
region.notifyOnExit = false
localNotification.region = region       

localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) is a link from Apple, about *Getting the User’s Location*